# Adding SignalR to the Website Makes Pages Load in Minutes

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, signalr, razor-pages

I have a simple Asp.Net Core 5 website. I added a hub and SignalR to the website. However, when I pushed the website to production they said the website slowed down significantly. This is the summary of what I did:

1.Added the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Core` package version `1.1.0`

2.Created an empty hub:

```
public class NotificationHub : Hub
{
}
```

3.In the code called it like so:

```
public class NotificationService
{
    public NotificationService(ApplicationDbContext db, IHubContext<NotificationHub> hub)
    {
        this.db = db;
        this.hub = hub;
    }

    public async Task AlertAllUsersAsync(Order order, string content, string icon)
    {
        //...

        await hub.Clients
            .Users(users.Select(u => u.Id.ToString()).ToList())
            .SendAsync("sendToUser", icon, content, link);
    }   
}
```

4.In Startup.cs added `services.AddSignalR();` and `endpoints.MapHub<NotificationHub>("/NotificationHub");`

5.And in JS:

```
var connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
    .withAutomaticReconnect()
    .withUrl("/NotificationHub")
    .build();

connection.on("sendToUser", (icon, content, link) => {
    showToast('info', content);
});

connection.start().catch(function (err) {
    return console.error(err.toString());
});
```

I tested on the server. Each page takes at least 1 minute to load. Sometimes even much longer. However, and as soon as I remove these lines of JS code, it works fast. I have never had any issues with SignalR, although this is the first time I'm using it in Asp.Net Core.

Comment: I see nothing wrong with the JS code. Isn't the problem inside showToast()?

Comment: Are you using SPA middleware to proxy dev server?

Comment: @leotuna The showToast is a very simple code. I know for a fact that it's not the issue. I even replaced it with console.log. Same issue

Comment: @abdusco No. I'm not.

Comment: When you increase the log level of everything to `Debug` (to see Kestrel's logs), where does the application spend the most time?

Comment: @abdusco for some reason today the website is not slow anymore. Adding signalR didn't change anything. I don't know what to make of it.